# Replace or add a new connection string in app.config

Tags: c#, web-config, connection-string, app-config

Actually, I have a connection string in **web.config**, and that connection I use for my current project.

I have also a **testing project**, so I want to point to another connection string in this one. Both databases have the same structure, the difference is I don't want to affect the database of my current project. Could I point to another connection string in the app.config of my testing project?

Comment: Yes, you can create a connection string in your app.config of the test project and then reference that one instead.

Comment: I tried to point the new connection string in app.config, but unfortunately when I run my testing project, the connection string of web.config always is taken, the only difference in the connection strings is that point in different databases.I had heard something about external configuration files but is the same result.

Comment: One approach is to use [web.config transformations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Rather a nuisance to sort out the first time, but a useful way to be able to change various configuration values depending on the build.

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely, you can have a separate `app.config` or `web.config` file in your unit test project and there you can define a separate connection string pointing to a different server either local or remote all together.